# When integrating by subsitution, once you find the function $u$ and $du$, what function should I integrate?

Tags: integration, substitution

I understand that whenever we have a function to integrate, and we decide to use the method of variable change, what function should we integrate. For example, suppose this problem:

$ \int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{3}}}$
I decided that I will use the new function $u=\sqrt{1-x^{3}}$, and so $du=\frac{-3x^{2}}{2\sqrt{1-x^{3}}}$ or simply $\frac{-3x^{2}}{2u}$

Now, what goal should I keep in my mind when deciding what to put instead of the question mark here:
$\int_{a}^{b}? du$ ? Should I just put $1/u$? Or something else?

Comment: Well if it's in the form $g(f(x))f'(x)dx$ for some functions $g$ and $f$, then you clearly want to set $u=f(x)$.  Otherwise, you just sorta have to guess.  In your particular example I don't know that there's an elementary antiderivative, though.

Comment: WA finds a form in terms of the Hypergeometric function. Might be able to represent in terms of other special functions,  but that's probably the best you're going to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's change the integral into something that's actually solvable.
$$\int\frac{x^2dx}{\sqrt{1-x^3}}$$
The goal of substitution is to get rid of all instances of $x$, including the $dx$ (which is missing in your question). For this integral, the $x^3$ and $x^2dx$ look promising, so let's use
$$u=1-x^3$$
$$du = -3x^3dx \implies -\frac{1}{3}du = x^2dx$$
Substituting in $u$ and $du$:
$$\int\frac{-\frac{1}{3}du}{\sqrt{u}} = -\frac{1}{3}\int u^{-1/2}du = -\frac{2}{3}u^{1/2} = -\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{u}$$
Reversing the substiution:
$$ = -\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{1-x^3}$$
In order to integrate, all of the non-constant variables have to be the same. In this substitution, if $dx$ is not replaced and I get
$$\int\frac{x^2dx}{\sqrt{u}},$$
then I can't do the integral since there are multiple moving parts: $x$ and $u$.

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Great explanations, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you set $u=\sqrt{1-x^{3}}$, 
then 
$$du=\frac{-3x^{2}}{2\sqrt{1-x^{3}}} \color{red}{dx}.\tag1$$

Don't forget the $dx$ on the right-hand side! Also use $dx$ when writing the integral:
$$\int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{3}}}\color{red}{dx}.
$$
Consistent use of $dx$ will make the formal
manipulations a lot clearer.

From Equation (1) we get
$$dx=\frac{2\sqrt{1-x^{3}}}{-3x^{2}} du,$$
and we can use this equation to simply substitute $\dfrac{2\sqrt{1-x^{3}}}{-3x^{2}} du$ for $dx$ in the integral:
$$
\int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{3}}} dx
= \int_{a}^{b}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{3}}}\right)
   \frac{2\sqrt{1-x^{3}}}{-3x^{2}}  du
= -\frac23\int_{a}^{b} \frac{1}{x^{2}}  du.
$$

That's correct, but not simple to solve, since we still need to
convert the $x^2$ in the denominator into some function of $u$.
It turns out $x^2 = (1 - u^2)^{2/3}$, so we end up with
$$
-\frac23\int_{a}^{b} \frac{1}{(1 - u^2)^{2/3}}  du,
$$
which is not really an improvement over the original form of the integral.
The obvious substitutions don't always work, and this is one of the
cases where they do not.